# Why does the Vlasov equation not consider higher order time derivatives?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics

The Vlasov equation is given by: 
$$ \frac {df}{dt} = \frac {\partial f}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \cdot \frac {\partial f} {\partial \vec{x}} + \vec{a} \cdot \frac {\partial f} {\partial \vec{v}} $$

But why are higher order time-derivatives such as $ \frac {\partial \vec{a}} {\partial t} $ or $\frac {\partial f} {\partial \vec{a}}$ not included? Are they simply considered small or are they absolutely zero for some reason?

Comment: Hint: What does $f$ depend on?

Comment: Perhaps the very basic question is: why does $f$ only depend on $t$, $\vec{x}$, and $\vec{v}$? Why are these variables considered independent of one another and why is the distribution not dependent on higher order terms?

Comment: @Mathews24 The equation of motion depend on the Langragian no? Most Langragian's in physics do not depend on higher order terms